# Creating a Dialog confirmation with multiple selection

Tags: python, kivymd

Trying to make a Dialog popup in which the user selects multiple options, but so far, I can only select one of the options. Dug around and cannot figure out how to do this.

Here's the relevant parts of my code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem, OneLineAvatarIconListItem


##################################################################
# list display class
class ItemConfirm(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    divider = None

    def set_icon(self, instance_check):
        instance_check.active = True
        check_list = instance_check.get_widgets(instance_check.group)
        for check in check_list:
            if check != instance_check:
                check.active = False

class BaseScreen(Screen):

    def status_filter(self):
        if not self.filter_dialog:
            self.filter_dialog = MDDialog(
                title='Status Filter',
                type='confirmation',
                items=[
                    ItemConfirm(text='Own'),
                    ItemConfirm(text='For Trade'),
                    ItemConfirm(text='Want to Play'),
                    ItemConfirm(text='Previously Owned'),
                    ItemConfirm(text='Pre-Ordered')
                ],
                buttons=[
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text='Cancel'
                    ),
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text='Select All'
                    ),
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text='Confirm'
                    )
                ]
            )
            self.filter_dialog.open()
```

and the relevant part of the kv file:

```
<ItemConfirm>
    on_release: root.set_icon(check)

    CheckboxLeftWidget:
        id: check
        group: "check"


MDFloatLayout:

    MDFlatButton:
        text: "ALERT DIALOG"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: app.show_confirmation_dialog()
```

It's pretty much a plain vanilla implementation of what is shown on https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/dialog/

As it is, it only allows me to select one of the options and would like to be able to make multiple selections

Comment: All good, figured out the answer: the problem is that my checkboxes were part of a group. Removing the group solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

All good, figured out the answer: the problem is that my checkboxes were part of a group. Removing the group solved my issue.